# How to find out whether a line present in one image is subset of another line present in different image using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-thresholding

I have two images say imageA and imageB as shown below. Now I need to check whether the line present in imageB already exists in image A or not (i.e) line present in imageB should be the subset of line present in imageA. I used image subtraction in open cv but not able to get desired output. I am a newbie to opencv. So someone please provide your inputs.

Note : Can have some threshold for line matching as the line in both images will not match 100% exactly.

ImageA :
[image]

ImageB :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach:

1. Take image A, threshold it and morphologically dilate it a little to allow for slight differences in position/alignment. A larger dilation will allow greater misalignment.

[image]

2. Take image B, threshold it. Count the non-zero pixels.
3. Do a bitwise AND of the two images and count how many pixels are white in the result - i.e. common to both images.

[image]

4. Calculate the ratio of the results from steps 2 and 3 to get a measure of the percentage of pixels in image B that are in, or very nearly in image A.

Comment: Hi @Mark Setchell in step 2 while counting the non-zero pixels whether that image should be dilated or can I take the raw input image. And also for doing the bitwise AND operation in step 3 both the images should be diluted right ?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you only dilate image A never B. I'm treating image A as the *"landing space"* where pixels of image B can land. If you dilate B, you will have a false measure of how many pixels are in image B... which will make your ratio calculation incorrect.

Comment: yeah got it. Thanks @Mark for this solution. 
Following are my results : 
Non-Zero Pixels Image B: 464
Non-Zero Pixels Bitwise: 407
Difference :57
So do u have any idea about determining the acceptable threshold ?

Comment: Glad it's working. I would say the tolerance is application-specific. Currently 87% of the white pixels in image B fall within dilated white pixels in image A. You could try dilating by 1 pixel in all directions, measure the ratio/percentage and see how you feel about that. Then start again and dilate by 2, measure the percentage and see how you feel. Then dilate by 3 until you feel the lines are insufficiently similar...

Comment: I updated the kernel size as (4,4),cv2.MORPH_CROSS with iterations=2.Now it is matching 100%.Thanks for this apporach @Mike